# Where can I get a "Light Table" theme for Emacs 24?

Tags: emacs, lisp, themes, emacs24

I really like the Light Table color scheme but despite lots of Googling I can't seem to find an Emacs theme. I've made an attempt to recreate it but surely someone else has done this already.

It's a dark theme that looks like:

[image: Light Table theme example]

There's a load more example images on the [Kickstarter page](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/ibdknox/light-table).

Comment: It would be great if you could share your recreation :)

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt https://gist.github.com/3027622 - There's one here.

Comment: Just a quick update, as found by people converting solarised to Emacs, the colorspace in Emacs isn't sRGB, it's generic RGB, so you need to use Apple's colorspace tool to convert rgb values from PNG's with sRGB to get the right hex colors.

Comment: By the way, if you checkout http://emacsfodder.github.com you can find a few of my other Emacs24 themes, and my personal .emacs is over at http://github.com/ocodo/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness it's probably worth adding this new answer here. There is now a LightTable theme for Emacs. It's called **Noctilux**:

https://github.com/stafu/noctilux-theme

Answer (score 7):

I made a theme based on the LightTable color scheme, I've just released it as a gist.

```
https://gist.github.com/3027622
```

[image: bubbleberry-theme.el]

FYI I'm publishing several new themes for Emacs24. There's a couple of other dark themes at https://emacsfodder.github.io/

#### Update

Here's a view of the font-lock (i.e. language generics, which are used by major modes to provide syntax highlighting.) definition with rainbow-mode.

[image: BubbleBerry Theme font-lock defs rainbow-mode]

#### Note:

In Emacs Lisp mode (CommonLisp & EmacsLisp are the closest things I know to Clojure.)

We can see that even local function usage isn't added to syntax highlighting:

[image: Local function usage isn't added to syntax highlighting in Emacs Lisp mode.]

(Having done a small check with clojure-mode, I can see the same thing going on there, defn's show their function name highlighted, but usage is in the default face color.)

Comment: Upvote for making the effort to put something together, thanks! Your theme is quite different to LightTable though, so no 'accept' for this answer yet. Using Clojure I see a lot of differences: function names when declared, function names when called, map keys. Almost there though.

Comment: @joelittlejohn FYI Clojure-mode would need to map these, Emacs font-lock has the following possible mappings that apply to general modes:  comment, comment-delimiter, string, doc, keyword, builtin, function-name, variable-name, type, constant, warning, negation-char, preprocessor, constant, reference - see the theme for how these map to the colors from that image, (it's the one I used as a reference btw.)

Comment: As we can see in the screen grab I've posted, there's no lexical recognition of function names, i.e. second, third, *, hexrgb-hsv-to-hex - even within Emacs lisp mode, and yet the font-lock-function-name-face is set to #3ca380 in the theme. (I've added a new image to show the face definitions.)

Comment: I should add that variables are also not properly highlighted in Emacs Lisp mode, even though the font-lock-variable-face is defined. If a major mode fails to manage it's font-lock properly. Themes cannot compensate.

Answer (score 0):

[Lighttable theme for Doom Emacs](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/sv23ll/doom_emacs_lighttable_theme/)